# Struggling to bind JSON data - JQuery Datatables

Tags: json, datatables

I am struggling to bind the JSON data into a Datatable. This is my Javascript code.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#searchForm').serialize(),
        url: "/ReportingItem/Search",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#searchResults').DataTable({
                data: data,
                dataSrc: "",
                columns: [
                    { "data": "ID" },
                    { "data": "ItemContent" }
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            if (xhr.status == 404) {
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        }

    });
```

This is my JSON

```
 "[{"ID":"3","ItemContent":"2nd Test"},{"ID":"4","ItemContent":"3rd Test"},{"ID":"9","ItemContent":"eeeeee"},{"ID":"11","ItemContent":"aaaa"}]"
```

You can see its a flat array. therefore I have used dataSRC="" so it doesn't  look for "data" in the JSON

This is the error message I am getting

> DataTables warning: table id=searchResults - Requested unknown
>   parameter 'ID' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this
>   error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Any help on the Syntax would be helpful!

Thanks

Chris

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above.  JSON and DT is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Just add in the data line

```
$('#searchResults').DataTable({
      data: JSON.parse(data),
       ....
});
```

> JSON.parse

Answer (score 0):

Just you have to check what json objects return in ReportingItem/Search.
as you mention:

```
"[{"ID":"3","ItemContent":"2nd Test"},{"ID":"4","ItemContent":"3rd Test"},{"ID":"9","ItemContent":"eeeeee"},{"ID":"11","ItemContent":"aaaa"}]"
```

in most case json format is camel notation format. it means object names start with lowercase. so you should make some changes in WebApiConfig or if its not api in a config which you set : ReportingItem/Search 
add this to the method Register:

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
            {
 var Settings = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
            Settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
            Settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
//... other codes
}
```

at the end instead of

```
columns: [
                    { "data": "ID" },
                    { "data": "ItemContent" }
]
```

use this:

```
columns: [
                        { "data": "iD" },
                        { "data": "itemContent" }
    ]
```

hope its done.